# Textarea Auto scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this can be done with the .change() event and put `$('#console').scrollTop($('#console')[0].scrollHeight);` in it.But problem is that textarea is readonly and I am using javascript to enter the text in textarea.

For ex:-

$('#console').text($('#console').text()+'\n>_ Optained Trigger');

In this case the textarea is not scrolltobottom because change event it not responding.

Any alternative for it or any other event that capture javascript text change in textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain jQuery operations that affect your element without the need of events:

```
$('#console').text($('#console').text()+'\n>_ Optained Trigger').scrollTop($('#console')[0].scrollHeight);
```

edit: Ok, I read your comments, and to solve that you could trigger the change event manually

```
//first define the event behaviour
$('#console').on('change', function(e){
    var console = $(this);
    console.scrollTop($('#console')[0].scrollHeight);
}

//then every time you modify the text, trigger the event
$('#console').text($('#console').text()+'\n>_ Optained Trigger').trigger('change')
```

Comment: Yes I can do that but this change in text in done at lot of places(in different files ) so I need an event to detect when their is a change in the textarea.

Comment: there is a input event also